# Query a history table to find state on a given date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created a history table that is populated by triggers on another "live" table. I now want to be able to see how it looked on a given date. I am able to query a single product using a where clause which gives me the desired output for a single product.

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE productid = 1
AND updated < '2020-02-15'
ORDER BY updated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But how do I get the last updated value before my given date (mid-Feb in this example) **for each product** in the table?

A simple version of my table looks like this:-

```
productid   amount  updated
1   5   01/01/2020
1   6   01/02/2020
1   7   01/03/2020
2   13  01/01/2020
2   14  01/02/2020
2   15  01/04/2020
```

and my desired outcome is:

```
productid   amount  updated
    1   6   01/02/2020
    2   14  01/02/2020
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (productid) t.*
from test t
where updated < date '2020-02-15'
order by productid, updated desc
```